# SQL time 24 hour to 12 hour format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my table something like this:

```
+----------------+------------+
|      Date      +    Time    |
|-----------------------------|
| 2015-09-23     | 17:20:25   |
| 2015-09-23     | 17:25:27   |
| 2015-09-24     | 06:29:27   |
-------------------------------
```

I want only to get the time column and I want it to display in 12 hour format. Something like this:

```
5:20 P.M.
5:25 P.M.
6:29 A.M.
```

I used this query: `SELECT time FROM attendance WHERE 1`

Comment: Which database? MSSQL, MYSQL, Oracle.....?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 5):

try this (For MSSQL)

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15),Time,100) from attendance where 1
```

For MYSQL

```
select TIME_FORMAT(Time, '%r') from attendance where 1
```

Comment: TIME_FORMAT(Time, '%r');

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server you can try like this:

```
declare @t time
set @t = '17:20:25'

select CONVERT(varchar(15),@t,100)
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2184)

In MYSQL you can use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with %p specifier. Like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2015-09-24 16:21:50', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/22238)

or simply

```
select TIME_FORMAT('17:20:25', '%r');
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/22239)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this too

```
TIME_FORMAT(Time, '%h:%i %p')
```

Output : **06:40 PM**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
DECLARE @aux NVARCHAR(8)='16:45:00'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(@aux AS TIME),100)
```

or

```
declare @t time
set @t = '17:20:25'

select CONVERT(varchar(15),@t,100)
```

result:

```
5:20PM
```

Comment: Please specify dbms this works with. (Non ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: So why not edit your answer and tell us which dbms product it works with?